# Java program to find the IP addresses of the following websites: Facebook , google , yahoo in the same try and catch

Tags: java

here is my code for one website but i need to make multiple ip's in same try and catch

```
package javaapplication1;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class JavaApplication1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         try {
            InetAddress[] addresses = InetAddress.getAllByName("google.com");

            for (InetAddress address : addresses) {
                System.out.println(address);


            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            System.out.println("Could not find");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is a site for real programmers and people who want to become programmers.  It is not a place to ask people to write (or modify) your code for you.  Seriously, even a beginner Java programmer should know how to write a simple loop ... or take an argument from the command line.  If you don't know this, can I recommend that you read the Oracle Java Tutorial ... or a Java text book.

Answer (score 2):

Make a list of Facebook,Google and yahoo

Iterate over the list and then use `InetAddress.getAllByName(list.get(index))`

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Facebook");// can add more urls
        for (String ip : list) {
            try {
                InetAddress[] addresses = InetAddress.getAllByName(ip);

                for (InetAddress address : addresses) {
                    System.out.println(address);

                }
            } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
                System.out.println("Could not find");
            }
        }
```

Comment: i mean what is the way or the code to add another url

Comment: you mean to say.. store all addresses??

Comment: @Ali Raphal, @Aj's answer is the way to add other urls... just add more `list.add(`instructions with the other urls....

Comment: Another way would be to grab the URLs from the command line arguments.